# useEffect returning an empty array on first mount in React

Tags: reactjs

**context/cart.jsx**

```
import { useState, useContext, createContext, useEffect } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext()

const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
    const existingCartItems = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    console.log(existingCartItems)

    useEffect(() => {
        setCart(JSON.parse(existingCartItems));
    }, [existingCartItems])

    console.log(cart)

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={[cart, setCart]}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}

const useCart = () => useContext(CartContext)

export { useCart, CartProvider }
```

**pages/CartPage.jsx**

```
const CartPage = () => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useCart() <-- The value returning an empty array on first mount
}
```

I am trying to mount the value of cart with the local storage value instead of an empty array. What is the reason the `cart` returns an empty array on other component pages even I already used `useEffect` to set the value. How to have the `cart` returning the value in the local storage instead of returning an empty array on first mount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like encountering an issue with the initial state of your cart when your component mounts. The reason you're seeing an empty array on the first mount is due to the sequence of operations and the asynchronous nature of useState and useEffect.

1. You initialize **cart** with an empty array using **useState**.
2. The CartPage component mounts, and at this point, cart is still an empty array because **useEffect** has not run yet.
3. **useEffect** runs after the component mounts, but setting the state is asynchronous. So if you try to access cart immediately after the component mounts (such as in CartPage), it will still be an empty array.

   ```
    const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const existingCartItems = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(existingCartItems ? JSON.parse(existingCartItems) : []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (existingCartItems) {
            setCart(JSON.parse(existingCartItems));
        }
    }, [existingCartItems])

    // ...

    return (
        // ...
    )
   ```

   }

Comment: Yes that is what I want as I need to handle the quantity change in other components

Answer (score 1):

UseEffect will not call when changing local storage. So that's why getting an empty array.

At a first mount, this will only work

```
import { useState, useContext, createContext, useEffect } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext()

const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
    const existingCartItems = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    console.log(existingCartItems)

    useEffect(() => {
      const parsedCart = JSON.parse(existingCartItems);
      setCart(parsedCart || []);
    }, []);

    console.log(cart)

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={[cart, setCart]}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}

const useCart = () => useContext(CartContext)

export { useCart, CartProvider }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that setCart is called on the initial mount with the parsed cart items even if existingCartItems is initially null or undefined. If existingCartItems is null, it will skip the setCart call because the if (parsedCart) check will fail. This way, you prevent setCart from being called with an empty array on the initial mount.

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
const parsedCart = JSON.parse(existingCartItems);
if (parsedCart) {
    setCart(parsedCart);
} }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a default value of an empty array [] if existingCartItems is falsy like this :-

```
const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(() => {
        const existingCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
        return existingCartItems || []; // Provide default value of empty array if null
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    }, [cart]);

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={[cart, setCart]}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

From this code,if existingCartItems is null,it will default to an empty array and ensure that the value of cart is initialized correctly when the component mounts.

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply do;

```
const existingCartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || [];

useEffect(() => {
    setCarts(existingCartItems);
}, [existingCartItems.length])
```